# What it is the best way to perform a task in background (thread or call method from application_start)?

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net.

I am going to develop a way to display results from fedex's service (every 2 hours) in my website. I have searched,I found a lot of options, and chose two of them:

**1: From application start**

```
private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 60*60*2);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
    // re-add our task so it recurs
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

More info : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

**2: Using thread**

```
System.Threading.Thread OrderStatusFromFedexThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(OrderStatusChange));
OrderStatusFromFedexThread.IsBackground = true;
OrderStatusFromFedexThread.Name = "OrderStatusFromFedexThread";
OrderStatusFromFedexThread.Start();

  public static bool ShutDown = false;


    static void OrderStatusChange()
    {
        while (!ShutDown)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((1000 * 60) * 60 *2);
              // do stuff here 
        }
    }
```

My question is: what is the best way:

1. Add a task from application start or
2. Using thread?

Which keeps the speed of website faster, and doesn't make it slow?

Comment: Your intended need sounds a little odd  Maybe you could elaborate a little.  How much fedex data are you getting every 2 hours?  Why not just do on demand calls when someone hits your site?  When the app pool recycles and all the memory is flushed.  If this is a performance concern, the first person to hit the site will take a beating.

Comment: @Adam47..I need to do that every 2 or 4 hours in background ..

Comment: I'd rather have a webpage or web service, and have a background service (console, windows service, etc) visit the page or call the web service at the set interval.

Comment: Couldn't you set up an update panel with a timer? That way the information is updated within the update panel and nothing is running in the background and performance loss shouldn't be an issue. If this wasn't a website but a Windows Forms Application, then either of the options above would be okay to use.

Comment: @JWLim .. i read some thing related ..could you please give me an example or website url that help me to discover this way ..

Comment: @Humpy ..this is an website..so i am looking to use one of them in my website what about performance ??!! –

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud I answered it showing you how to use an update panel with a timer. Let me know if that's a solution for you.

Comment: SignalR would be the right candidate here since you are looking for a Long Running Job - refer http://www.kolls.net/blog/?p=92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it with a timer and an update panel.

```
//timer that can be set to any time you want. Interval is miliseconds
<asp:Timer ID="UpdateGridTimer" runat="server" Interval="7200000" OnTick="UpdateGridTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TimedPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        //this trigger calls the timer every 2 hours. 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateGridTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    // Here is where you'd display the fedex information. 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This should do it for you. I use this method for an appointment system.

EDIT: The above is the front end of your code, so you will use that to display your information. I'm not sure how you have it set up, but if you're using (for example) a gridview, you can bind that gridview on tick.. and it would look like this..

ASPX

```
//timer that can be set to any time you want. Interval is miliseconds
    <asp:Timer ID="UpdateGridTimer" runat="server" Interval="7200000" OnTick="UpdateGridTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="TimedPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            //this trigger calls the timer every 2 hours. 
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateGridTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:gridview id="GridView1" runant="server">
               //gridview content
          </asp:gridview> 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#

```
protected void UpdateGridTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //this would be the code to update the gridview.
  //you can use a data table and bind the results to the gridview
  //in your case, you will do whatever it is you have to do get the fed ex information
  // but I'm not sure how you are doing this to show you. 

       GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Sorry I left the behind code out of it in my previous answer. What the onTick does, after the 2 hours, it will run the code for that timer tick. So every two hours, it will act like your button click, but it requires no human interaction. The website just needs to be up. But since the timer is every two hours, you must make sure that the session timeout doesn't kick you off every two hours. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: //You're code here to get the fedex information--I need to press specific button to perform my process and get the fedex information ..so how i can use your code ?

Comment: If you're using the timer.. it will act like your button. The timer is so you don't have to physically post back back. I'll update my answer to better explain it.

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud check out my edit to my post. Hopefully that explains it more for you.

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud did you have any luck with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't want to consume threads in an asp.net site.  However, there are plenty of exceptions.  Either implementation will do what you want (provided you're not blocking Application_Start from finishing in your threading example).  
 Most likely the caching option will burn some CPU periodically to see if stuff is expired.  You may want to dig into the details of the caching implementation.  This would be more important if you're hosting in Azure and paying for CPU.  
The threading example is going to burn a thread, but since it's only one for the app pool it probably does not matter. 
 Most likely the biggest concern is this whole thing is completely dependent on holding everything in memory.  It seem very odd that you would need to do that.  If you really needed to gather a big chunk of data every couple of hours, some scheduled service that puts data into a local database might make more sense.  Then let your website connect to that database.  Unless you're just trying to do statistical reporting, it seems odd that this stale data would be acceptable to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a JavaScript timer to make an AJAX call to a WebService and reload the page client side without post back.

The solution provided by @Humpty is also good.

I hope this helps.